# How to set the radius for rounded node style?

Tags: graphviz

I have a graph with rounded nodes. How can I influence the radius of the rounding? Or do I need to accept the graphviz setting as fixed? What is the exact default setting?

```
digraph G { 
    node [shape=rectangle style=rounded]
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Sorry guy, i've the same pb.
Looking on source code ... it's hard coded to 12 !

**shapes.c#18 => #define RBCONST 12**

No way to change it.
The only way is to modify svg generated:

- dont use rounding anymore
- found:

```
<polygon fill="#8a2be2" stroke="#8a2be2" points="194,-344 140,-344 140,-308 194,-308 194,-344"></polygon>
```

- replace by:

```
<rect x="140" y="-344" rx="5" ry="5" width="54" height="36" style="fill: rgb(181, 157, 224);stroke: rgb(138, 43, 226);stroke-width: 1px;opacity: 1;"></rect>
```